# Is there a simple way to calculate the linear regression slope based on multiple points?

Tags: r

```
data <- data.frame(Year1 = c(4, 2), Year2 = c(0, 10), Year3 = c(5, 6), Year4 = c(18, 4))
```

Given the 2 rows/observations above which contains 4 years/columns. I'd like to get R to calculate the slope of the linear regression line based on all 4 points for each observation.

The slope value should appear in a new column to the right of the data frame.

```
slope_data <- data.frame(Year1 = c(4, 2), Year2 = c(0, 10), Year3 = c(5, 6), Year4 = c(18, 4), Slope = c(5, 5))
```

I was wondering if there was a simple function or package that could achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments,  this will be needed for more than two rows.  You can use `lm` to get the needed slope for one row and use `sapply` to get it for all rows.

```
Slope = function(x) {
    TempDF = data.frame(x, year=1:ncol(data))
    lm(x ~ year, data=TempDF)$coefficients[2]
}

TData = as.data.frame(t(data))
data$slope = sapply(TData, Slope)
data
  Year1 Year2 Year3 Year4 slope
1     4     0     5    18   4.7
2     2    10     6     4   0.2
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! You're right that slopes may not benefit this data, but that is because I'm using a sample data, whereas my real data has a few thousand observations. With that being said, would there be a more automatic way of finding the slope for many observations in just one code?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can you explain to me what the **$coefficients[2]** part is referring to?

Comment: The `lm` function returns a complex structure. One piece of it is the coefficients - the slope and the intercept. The intercept is $coefficients[1]. The slope is $coefficients[2].  If you save one of the linear models   `LM =lm( ... )`  and then type `str(LM)` you can see all of the things that are returned.

Comment: That's really helpful. Thank you so much!